# Набор информации всегда начинается с начала строки для поля ввода input

Tags: javascript, wordpress, input

Всем привет!

Работаю с сайтом на WordPress. Тип поля набора информации - мобильный телефон.

Есть задача:

Настроить поле ввода таким образом, чтобы куда ни кликнул пользователь в рамках данного поля, набор цифр всегда начинается с самого начала, а не от туда куда он кликнул. А если в поле уже набраны какие то цифры, набор новых символов будет продолжать с того места, где стоит последний символ.

Был написан следующий код на JS:

```
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="tel"]'), function (input) {
    let keyCode;
    function mask(event) {
      event.keyCode && (keyCode = event.keyCode);
      let pos = this.selectionStart;
      if (pos < 3) event.preventDefault();
      let matrix = '+7 (___) ___-____',
        i = 0,
        def = matrix.replace(/\D/g, ''),
        val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, ''),
        new_value = matrix.replace(/[_\d]/g, function (a) {
          return i < val.length ? val.charAt(i++)  def.charAt(i) : a
        });
      i = new_value.indexOf('_');
      if (i != -1) {
        i < 5 && (i = 3);
        new_value = new_value.slice(0, i)
      }
      var reg = matrix.substr(0, this.value.length).replace(/_+/g,
        function (a) {
          return '\\d{1,' + a.length + '}'
        }).replace(/[+()]/g, '\\$&');
      reg = new RegExp('^' + reg + '$');
      if (!reg.test(this.value)  this.value.length < 5  keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58) this.value = new_value;
      if (event.type == 'blur' && this.value.length < 5) this.value = ''
    }
    input.addEventListener('input', mask, false);
    input.addEventListener('focus', mask, false);
    input.addEventListener('blur', mask, false);
    input.addEventListener('keydown', mask, false);
  });
```

Данным кодом удалось решить изначально поставленную задачу, но появилась новая проблема: последние две набранные цифры меняются местами (например: набираешь с клавиатуры 57, а в поле вода отображается 75).

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?
Как всегда заранее низкий поклон!

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, крайний с конца

Comment: Нужно срочно начинать писать на питухоне :)

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, все для вас, поправил. мне бы получить ответ на мой вопрос, вроде суть понятна..

Comment: Скажу что ты делаешь не так - придумал идиотскую затею. Как по твоему человеку будет удобно исправить неверно написанную цифру?

Comment: @SeVlad, два варианта:
- он удаляет до того места, где указана неверная цифра и званого набирает корректный номер
- он выделяет неверную цифру и вводит новую.

Идея задачи выше в том, чтобы упростить набор номера, если пользователь случайно кликнул не в начало строки, а например в середину